# Install Ubuntu from usb

Tags: system-installation, usb-creator

I need to install Ubuntu server without CD/DVD driver. I have read a guide to make a bootable USB using windows, but on my other PC I have Mac OS. Can I make a bootable USB from Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you look [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) you can find the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) to burn the disc.
Step 10 also says:

> Restart your Mac and press alt/option key while the Mac is restarting to choose the USB stick.

You can then use [these](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) instructions to install, or other instructions like [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/MacOSX) (or [these](http://lifehacker.com/5934942/how-to-dual-boot-linux-on-your-mac-and-take-back-your-powerhouse-apple-hardware)) if you want to dual boot (Mac+Ubuntu). You may need to pick the Ubuntu version specified [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/CommunityHelpPages)

Comment: but with this how-to i can use the bootable usb (create under Mac Os) on a "normal" pc?